# select a value inside of a dropdown menu by the text value

Tags: css, python-2.7, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down menus on the same window. Both of their codes are the same however the values are different.

The first drop down menu:

```
    <div style="width: 302px; display: block; top: 263px; left: 193px;" 
    class="number_combo_list  FullWidthField">    
<div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">One</div>
<div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">Two</div>
<div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">Three</div>
```

The second drop down menu:

```
<div style="width: 302px; display: block; top: 263px; left: 193px;" 
        class="number_combo_list  FullWidthField">    
    <div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></div>
    <div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">Fries</div>
    <div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">Steak</div>
    <div class="" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">Chicken</div>
```

I want to select the **steak** inside of the second drop down menu. However, whenever I try I end up clicking the first drop down menu. I know I can use the xpath but I want to use the css_selector. **Is there a way to select a value inside of a dropdown menu by the text value?**

Comment: what is wrong with using `xpath`?) ...and also clarify what you mean to select value by value?

Comment: The webpage is still in development so the path may change. I mean that I want to know if I select the text value of an option.

Answer (score 0):

Please not that the following is CSS3 compliant methods, and should work versions above IE8 browser version

```
div.number_combo_list:nth-of-type(2)
```

or

```
div.number_combo_list:nth-child(2)
```

In case you have code you are trying, please post that, so that we can point out issue in the code, and provide most relevant answer.